# Panda Dataframe manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can anyone explain to me how to solve this problem.

Let's say i have a dataframe like:

```
Df = {'toto': ["A", "B", "C", "D"], 
      'titi': ["g", "t", "x", "z"],
      'Energy': [180, 345, 234, 654],
      'T10sec': [0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 1], 
      'T50sec': [5.3, 5.7, 8, 2]}
```

For this `Df` i've created a function like

```
def record(letter1, letter2, Energy_value, time):
```

What i want to do it's

Check if : the enter values are in this `Df` , if `yes` then

```
Results = Df.thecorrespondingtime[i]
```

Assume that for the columns `'toto'` and `'titi'` the input letter are in `Df`, two cases are possible:

Case1: the input `'Energy_value'` is in `Df` but not the `'time'`value then i have to find the range of this value and create its column  and fill it with interpolation.

Case 2: the column value of `'time'` exists but the input Energy value no. Here again i need to do an interpolation.

My limitations are:
How to check if the `'time'` column exists and how to put between two existing values.
The same question for the input Energy value.

Here , what i tried:

```
def record(letter1, letter2, Energy_value, time='T15sec'):
    For i in range(len(Df)):
        If ((df.toto[i] == letter1) and 
            (df.titi[i] == letter2) and 
            (df.Energy[i] == Energy_value) and 
            (time in df)):
```

But it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's going to happen after the final if-clause? Looks like there is some code missing. And where are you actually defining your dataframes?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Did you see Df ( this is the data frame) .  After the final,  if the different values matche .. the 'Result' is return

Comment: Df  is not a dataframe, but a dictionary. However, your description of the required interpolation is rather vague and this is nothing the stackoverflow community can help you with.

Comment: Thank you Peter for editing my post, and sorry if i am not clear enough. How do i add  a new column between two existing in a dataframe? ( an order should exists) .  I will read the difference between dictionary and dataframe.

Comment: If i have three columns: A - D- E in a dataframe.  If i have a function which takes as argument the name of the column name ..for example .. the input is 'B' , firstly i want to check if that 'B' column exist .. if not has B is between  A and D , create a new column between A and D and name it B. Is there anyway  that i can do that?  Thank you.

Comment: I understand my mistake, i didn't finish..                                                after Df création,  should be df1 = pd.DataFrame(Df, columns=['toto', 'titi', 'Energy '..])

Comment: Should i delete this post and start a new one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is basically about inserting another time column into the dataframe this would be a solution:

```
import pandas as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'toto': ["A", "B", "C", "D"], 
      'titi': ["g", "t", "x", "z"],
      'Energy': [180, 345, 234, 654],
      'T10sec': [0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 1], 
      'T50sec': [5.3, 5.7, 8, 2]})
df
    toto    titi    Energy  T10sec  T50sec
0   A       g       180     0.1     5.3
1   B       t       345     0.4     5.7
2   C       x       234     0.5     8.0
3   D       z       654     1.0     2.0
```

Add time column:

```
import numpy as np
time = 'T15sec'

if not time in df:
    df[time] = np.NaN

df.iloc[:, 3:] = df.iloc[:, 3:].T.sort_index().interpolate().T

df[['toto', 'titi', 'Energy', 'T10sec', time, 'T50sec']]

    toto    titi    Energy  T10sec  T15sec  T50sec
0   A       g       180     0.1     2.70    5.3
1   B       t       345     0.4     3.05    5.7
2   C       x       234     0.5     4.25    8.0
3   D       z       654     1.0     1.50    2.0
```

Comment: Thank you Peter. The answer solves a part of my question. Thank you so much.